# Accordion not working on getting the inner contents (HTML) from jsp script

Tags: html, ajax, jquery, accordion

I am writing the code for getting the accordion contents when I click on  the button. The inner contents for the accordion are being received from the sever using ajax call.These contents are displayed inside a dialog box.

Now the problem is that the contents (originally supposed to be accordion contents) can be seen in the dialog box as simple html and not as accordion (with buttons). If I just use the same contents in  the html file(paste the contents received from the server inside the "" they work fine and I can see the accordion in the dialog box.

Whats going wrong? Is it related to that the accordion contents need to be given before hand. Can anyone suggest a way to fix this. (the contents of the accordion will change every time that's why they are being received from the server)

Javascript function is:

```
<script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#accordion").accordion({
    autoHeight: false
});
     </script>


<script language="javascript"> 

    function Faulttest() 
    {

    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();}
    else
    {xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");}
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    Here we get the contents which should be inside the accordion which we receive from the server



> **document.getElementById("accordion").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;**



    }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","http://****/Anomalies/index.jsp",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Html contents of page are:

```
<body style="font-size:62.5%;"  >
        <div id="page">         
        <div id="header"><h1>header</h1></div>          
        <div id="body" >
            <h1>content top </h1>                       
        <div id="dia">
        <div id="dialog" title="Detailed FeedBack"><div id="accordion">

        // CODE SHOULD GO HERE


        </div>
            </div>
                </div>
   <button type="button" onclick="Faulttest();">Click Me!</button>  
  </body>
```

Comment: How are you initializing the accordion?

Comment: I am initializing before the javascript (Faulttest)

Comment: Why are you not using the JQuery $.ajax() function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing exactly how the accordion script works, I'm assuming it's because the script assumes that the contents within the `#accordion` upon initialization are the contents with which the script will need to work with.

If it's possible with your implementation, put empty `div`s inside the `#accordion` (or whatever the accordion script specifies for child nodes) and populate those dynamically instead.

Otherwise, wait to initialize the accordion on the `#accordion` node until after the AJAX call is returned.

Comment: Thanks. I did included different div's and added the accordion tags and contents dynamically but in that case I was not even able to view the html contents returned. So I hard coded the accordion tags in the html script itself.

Comment: It is still not working. I tried initializing the accordion after the ajax call as well as before both doesn't work.

Comment: Okay, so in your `#accordion`, you have DIVs in HTML (static). Then, in your AJAX callback, you put the accordion instantiation code. Correct?

Comment: Please find the HTML contents of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Actually we just need to destroy and re-create the accordion.This can be done as follows:

```
$('#accordion').append(xmlhttp.responseText).accordion('destroy').accordion();
```